# Get path for all files in folder exclude 1 file. Command Line

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am trying get path all files and folder in indicated path and except folder Sql as a list. Only folders in the indicated location, no subfolders and their contents.

I am trying this:

```
powershell Get-ChildItem bin\Release\* -Exclude Sql -Name
```

But it return only name without path. I need `bin\Release\ + Name` or full path.

I was trying to:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %a in (`dir /b/n "bin\Release\*"`) do echo bin\Release\%~a
```

But don't know how change echo to list, and how remove folder Sql.

I will be grateful for your help, I cannot cope with it myself.

Comment: `(Get-ChildItem bin\Release\* -Exclude Sql).FullName`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it returns the contents of deeper folders. I had to remove "\\*" and it work good. Thanks.